# Get file descriptor from file name in C

Tags: c, file-descriptor

Is is possible to get a file descriptor from a file path in C? And if not, what is the standard way of generating a file descriptor in C?

See below for what I'm trying to do with a file descriptor:

```
char file[] = "/tmp/run"

int file_descriptor = /* fill in code to get file descriptor */

fchmod(file_descriptor, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR)
```

Comment: I don't think there is a standard C way of doing that. Within POSIX, the standard way is to use [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html). Alternatively, you can use [fopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) then [fileno](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html).

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/open.html

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what the POSIX [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) function does: It gives you a file descriptor that refers to the path you passed in.

(Note that neither `open` nor file descriptors in general are part of standard C.)